# How to force test, executed with ts-jest, to use node_modules in another folder?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I have the following folder structure, the unique twist of which is the common shared via symlink.

```
root
├── projects
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── common (symlink ../common)
│   │   ├── srcA.ts
│   │   └── testA.ts
│   ├── B
│   │   ├── node_modules
│   │   ├── common (symlink ../common)
│   │   ├── srcB.ts
│   │   └── testB.ts
│   └── common
│       ├── srcC.ts
│       └── testC.ts
```

Note that the symlinked folder, **common** doesn't have its own node_modules. Instead, it is using the node_modules of each project separately. This setup works fine during regular runtime, but during tests, I am getting errors.

I've originally hoped that I can simply use **jest** in the same way I run the projects. However, jest is [unable to follow symlinks](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1477). Due to that I've made the following **jest.config.js** (note that `roots` loads tests both from the `src` of the project and also from `common`):

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: "./",
  roots: ["../common/", "src/"],
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  resolver: "jest-pnp-resolver",
  setupFiles: ["react-app-polyfill/jsdom"],
  testMatch: ["**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  testURL: "http://localhost",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/scripts/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
    "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/scripts/config/jest/fileTransform.js",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$", "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
    "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
    "^src/(.*)": "<rootDir>/src/$1",
    "^common/(.*)": "<rootDir>/common/$1",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["web.js", "js", "web.ts", "ts", "web.tsx", "tsx", "json", "web.jsx", "jsx", "node"],
};
```

However, during tests **testC.ts** is unable to find the node_modules of its associated project. I've made several tries to force **ts-jest** to use the node_modules of the project:

```
module.exports = {
  moduleDirectories: ["/home/large-project/projects/A"],
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsConfig: {
        baseUrl: "/home/large-project/projects/A",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

However, it doesn't seem to change anything. How can I make typescript, via ts-jest, to tell `testC.ts` to use the node_modules in the project in which I am executing the test?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, have you figured out a solution?

Comment: @lukas1994 Sorry, no. I gave up on that structure and I am using regular node_commons in each project now.

Comment: what do you mean by node_commons ?

Comment: I meant node_modules. However, since I started using nx and their monorepo structure